# Is it possible to attach a .collection().doc() to doc.ref.path?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a new collection in the docPath in the example below. Is it possible to continue with .collection().doc()... after docPath (doc.ref.path)? I keep getting this error: cannot read property 'collection' of undefined.

My function where the error appears:

```
function comment(docPath) {

    var modalcomment = document.getElementById("modal-comment");

    modalcomment.style.display = "block";

    var submitcomment = document.getElementById("submitcomment");

    submitcomment.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        var commentinput = document.getElementById("comment");

        db.docPath.collection('comments').doc().set({

            comment: commentinput.value,

        })
        
    })

}
```

The code where I store the docPath variable:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    var query = db.collectionGroup("userPosts")

    query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
        setupPosts(querySnapshot.docs)
    })

    const posts = document.querySelector('.posts');

    const setupPosts = (data) => {
        let html = '';
        data.forEach(doc => {
            var docPath = doc.ref.path;
            console.log(docPath)
            const post = doc.data();
            const picURL = post.picURL;
            let li = `<li class="post">
                <div class="title">${post.title}</div>
                <div class="content">${post.content}</div>
                <button class="comment" onclick="comment('${docPath}')">Comment</button>
                <button class="like" onclick="like('${docPath}')">Like</button>`;
            
            li += (post.picURL ? `<img class="img" src="${post.picURL}" onclick="openImage('${picURL}')">` : ``);
            li += `</li><br></br>`;
            html += li
        })
        
        posts.innerHTML = html;
    }
```

docPath shows the correct stored data (the correct path of the document)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible with `doc.ref.path`, which is a string.  You can't call `collection()` on a string object.

Perhaps you want to store the value of [`doc.ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#ref) instead, which is a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) object.  That definitely has a [collection()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#collection) method that you can use to build build deeper references to subcollections under that document.

Comment: So, it's not possible to make a new collection with doc.ref.path? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I gave you the alternative in my answer.

Comment: So, that means that I can attach .collection() directly onto doc.ref. I can change doc.ref.path with doc.ref and it'll help me?

Comment: I suggest you try that, yes.

Comment: Error: docref.collection()..... is not a function. docref = doc.ref

Comment: Your code doesn't clearly show how db.docPath is linked to your second bit of code.  You're probably doing something wrong, but I can't see what it is.  You need to show a clear definition of db.docPath.

Comment: You mean how it is stored? docPath is stored into the comment button in the last code snippet in the question, and then used in the function comment(docPath).